# jQuery Animation: Moving objects

Tags: jquery, animation

This jquery code moves object top to bottom:

```
case
'slideToTop':
  $a.data('t',$a.css('top'));
  $a.stop().animate({'top': $a.height()+20 + 'px'},300,function(){
  $a.css('top',0-$a.height()-20 + 'px');
  $curr.removeClass('sh').hide();
  $next.addClass('sh').show();
  $a.animate({'top': $a.data('t')},300); }); 
break;
```

How would I change that to move object from bottom to top?

I tried modifying these lines:

```
$a.stop().animate({'top': $a.height()+20 + 'px'},300,function()
$a.css('top',0-$a.height()-20 + 'px');
```

To this:

```
$a.stop().animate({'top': 0-$a.height()-20 + 'px'},300,function(){
$a.css('top',$a.height()+20 + 'px');
```

Didn't work. Does anyone know? Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't look like very readable code...

Comment: My apologies. Am trying to make it more readable.

Comment: Try changing `top` to `bottom` in the original expression.

Comment: I tried that too and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the "px"

```
$a.stop().animate({'top': $a.height()+20},300,function(){$a.css('top',0-$a.height()-20 + 'px');
```

Comment: The same applies to all expressions

Comment: You've to check your CSS to make sure it's correct. To be able to animate any object based on position, you have to set the CSS position correctly (e.g. {position: relative}). Also check in your console to make sure the code is not generating any errors. Maybe you can post your code to jsfiddle and post a link.

Comment: I have position:absolute set on the parent container and position:relative set on the child.

Comment: Please can you inspect your console to check if any errors are being reported (**ctrl + shift + j** for FF and Chrome)